# How Can I Connect Each User To His Own Database?

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I have created a Cataloguer using PHP/MySQL. This Cataloguer will be distributed for some people (about 20+). All of them will have a specific database with there own cataloguer. Those database will be created by the ADM. But how can I redirect a user to his own database?

Right now the only thing I know about alternating from one database to another is by my dbh.php file:

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "user1";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

I have a login page the link to which I will send to these people. In that login page I want to make it so they fill in a key (each person has its specific key) that redirects them to a website (the cataloguer) and that cataloguer will use the database of that specific key only.

Comment: May be you can make a main database and store your users with their keys and redirect details in it. When a user tries to log in, check your main database if the user is registered and the key is true. So, you can redirect users to a desired website.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database for the users themselves and in it store the name and credentials for each user's own database. Once you log the user in then simply connect to the specific user's database.